# Классы миксины в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, композиция

Пример миксина:

```
export type CardConstructorOptions = { [key: string]: any };

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class Card {
  log() {
    console.log('Card');
  }
}

export function mixinContent<T extends Constructor<Card>>(super_class: T) {
  return class ContentMixin extends super_class {
    content() {
      console.log('content');
    }
  };
}

type ClassCard<T> = {
  [key: string]: Constructor<T>;
}

class CardContent extends mixinContent(Card) {

}

class Container {


  static create (name:string, options: CardConstructorOptions) {
    return new Container.store[name](options);
  }

  static get store(): ClassCard<Card|CardContent> {
    return {
      Card,
      CardContent,
    }
  }

}

const card = Container.create('CardContent', {}) as CardContent;

card.content();
```

Почему я не могу типизировать аргумент конструктора так:

```
type Constructor<T> = new (options: CardConstructorOptions) => T;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'.

[Песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBDKATNEB2AzjFAK4DGM0A8mDAJYGFwC8cA3nANoDWwiALjjEo9fAHMAukIz5EcAL4BuAFBqkKdExIUqUADwAVAHys4%20YAHc4ACgB0DrOMIy5XSQEpWpw6pUB6fwRkVDwiHUpoI1M2C2sbCDpGIiFMHDCRXRokpi8WHz9yABsMQmY07A4VODgiiHEbL3ZqmrhyJggi4Ds6hoByCr6PVRqFFTGVUEhYOAAzUnxKZLgAW3oQMTCYYHwYIzhQbfxscu0ySIMK42MbQlIUKAB9YtKXOEMmlqhgGFIofDaJTKWl2OxgAFl1mIDiAjidhPdgE8XsDmq02gQjjBGlV0TV2kROt1ejY%20gSsUMRq0xqNVBMNKEgYQKtEzGjuHxBMISGIpKkzlkDCY6WoUeUsLhMWCYXDmGsNvgtmCbBVPuNRUyQTAMGIkVU1DViBgGOQ2t9jagbPgMCtgAIRLyADRwRIMJipCUZCJ6WhuoifdHfX7-cxWLU6ixQOzEaDALjW22SBI5f1UiaG7UmuDiH7c2ONVJMlkVAA%20FSVu1M7JqQb%20AOrrQqjpa6PLUt2zfRNMUagmBOIbQlZi2EaRdnI5u2pLboN2fWd7AUXlK6E97ZghQl4-XjSUQA).

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQDcAWABQMhEwC2EJGCaZoMFgBMAMgEsARlADeMqOagQAHmFzAooSFADyYYHsRIyJqAEcqTFwA5P5MQVAAvmYW1rao9kwGKKhq9pgANkxIXgBCWdCm0hbFUJieaFg4qLRwbh7IXK7uniLGkdHmUUUWZcj2CnpWegjwCMAQY96EllbjCFpeo8mVuHh5SBBERLRI6JCoAPoZWZxQBCKkRB0lx9mwiHPAALKDwzNzC1C7+0eZd21dYoAeiBMziaT+i20PkBMRsdlKkNg0OsH1y+Rh11iCNuUNQWlGj3eE0+AyGIweE2AtE0+Na7W65koNFpBMpY1obVCwVC4QiQmuzOR+MJVM5fn8PICfIF0i6QA

Comment: Почему я не могу(C) - потому, что тогда TS не попадёт в топы SO : /

Comment: @qwabra Я уже решил проблему). Оформите ответ, я приму его так как он решает проблему в вопросе. А зачем вы использовали `namespace`?

Comment: "А зачем вы использовали namespace?" - для удобства, разбивал первоначальный код "по модулям" потом удалил лишнее(чтобы в коммент влезло) а это осталось ... "Я уже решил проблему" - отвечать на свой же вопрос - хорошая практика (по моему мнению). Правда, я бы в вопрос добавил код ошибки "TypeScript 2545" - для большей релевантности.